# Meaning of retrouver?

Tags: sens

I often hear the verb "retrouver" in YouTube videos. I looked it up in different dictionaries but I still can't quite pin down what is being meant.

For example:

> Je vous **retrouve** pour une nouvelle vidéo.

Does it mean *rejoindre* here? So it will be something like *I'm meeting you (the viewers) again for a new video*?

But what about this sentence:

> J’ai pris des questions de tous les tags, donc je *me* **retrouve** avec 30 questions.

Is this a reflexive use of *retrouver*? What does it mean here?

Does it literally mean *I find myself (again?) with 30 questions (~ I am in a situation where I have 30 questions)*. Then can '*se **re** + trouver*' be replaced here with just '*se trouver*'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have two different meanings of *se retrouver* here, and your understanding is correct for both:

- According to the [TLF dictionary (see II.B-1. and II.B-2.)](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/retrouver), one of the meanings of *se retrouver* is *too meet again* (after having been separate) or *too meet up* (an organized way).

  Its use is very common on TV, live shows, or radio, but not only.

  So your example:

  > Je vous retrouve pour une nouvelle vidéo !

  One could also say:

  > On se retrouve ce soir, les amis ? 
  > (*Shall we meet up tonight, friends?*)
- *I find myself (again)* can perfectly be translated into *je me retrouve (de nouveau)*: according to the same dictionary ([see II.A-2.b this time](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/retrouver)), another meaning of *se retrouver* is *to be facing an already known situation* or *to be suddenly facing a new situation*.

  So your example:

  > J’ai pris des questions de tous les tags, donc je me retrouve avec 30 questions.

  or

  > Hier, dans le métro, je me suis retrouvé face à un fou qui m'a menacé avec un couteau ! 
  > (*Yesterday, in the tube, I found myself in front of a crazy guy who threatened me with a knife!*)

  You can replace *retrouver* by *trouver* in this context. Both example above would work, regardless the fact this was a new situation. This is [the meaning II.C.2. of *trouver* in the TLF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver) which is *to be, at a given point of time, in a particular state, position or situation*.

  But note that *se trouver* and *se retrouver* cannot always be exchanged that way, this is limited to the context above:

  > Je vous trouve sympathique, c'est un plaisir. 
  > (*I find you sympathetic, that pleasant.*)

  Is not the same as

  > [Je vous ai quittée désagréable il y a un an.] Je vous retrouve sympathique, c'est un plaisir. 
  > (*[I used to find you unpleasant before we left each other a year ago]. Now that we meet again I find you sympathetic, that's pleasant*)